# What does the term bootstrap refer to in Python Multiprocessing.Process Module?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-internals

Playing with the Process and Pool modules in the Multiprocessing package and keep coming across references to the the `_bootstrap` method.

From what I'm seeing the method imports a `multiprocessing` `util.py` module and uses it's methods (combined with a few others) to `trace`, `log` and `manage` child processes.

```
def _bootstrap(self):
    from . import util
    global _current_process

    try:
        self._children = set()
        self._counter = itertools.count(1)
        try:
            sys.stdin.close()
            sys.stdin = open(os.devnull)
        except (OSError, ValueError):
            pass
        _current_process = self
        util._finalizer_registry.clear()
        util._run_after_forkers()
        util.info('child process calling self.run()')
        try:
            self.run()
            exitcode = 0
        finally:
            util._exit_function()
    except SystemExit, e:
        if not e.args:
            exitcode = 1
        elif isinstance(e.args[0], int):
            exitcode = e.args[0]
        else:
            sys.stderr.write(str(e.args[0]) + '\n')
            sys.stderr.flush()
            exitcode = 1
    except:
        exitcode = 1
        import traceback
        sys.stderr.write('Process %s:\n' % self.name)
        sys.stderr.flush()
        traceback.print_exc()

    util.info('process exiting with exitcode %d' % exitcode)
    return exitcode
```

Researched the term "bootstrap" a bit and see it used in various contexts within Python modules and most prominently (aside from maybe the twitter bootstrap framework) in reference to the process of measuring accuracy in statistics.

But in this case it seems like the function name might be referring to a method that ties various elements together? Is that the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `_bootstrap` function is what is run inside of a `multiprocessing.Process` immediately after it's created. Either [after it's forked](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0337a460f05b/Lib/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py#l67):

```
def _launch(self, process_obj):
    code = 1
    parent_r, child_w = os.pipe()
    self.pid = os.fork()
    if self.pid == 0:
        try:
            os.close(parent_r)
            if 'random' in sys.modules:
                import random
                random.seed()
            code = process_obj._bootstrap()
        finally:
            os._exit(code)
    else:
        os.close(child_w)
        util.Finalize(self, os.close, (parent_r,))
        self.sentinel = parent_r
```

Or [after it's spawned](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0337a460f05b/Lib/multiprocessing/spawn.py#l110):

```
def _main(fd):
    with os.fdopen(fd, 'rb', closefd=True) as from_parent:
        process.current_process()._inheriting = True
        try:
            preparation_data = pickle.load(from_parent)
            prepare(preparation_data)
            self = pickle.load(from_parent)
        finally:
            del process.current_process()._inheriting
    return self._bootstrap()
```

The `target` passed to the `Process` is executed from `_bootstrap`:

```
    try:
        self.run()  # This runs target.
        exitcode = 0
    finally:
        util._exit_function()
```

So "bootstrap" in this context is in reference to [bootstrapping (or more commonly these days, booting) a computer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping#Software_loading_and_execution). As in, the first stuff done when it starts up, that's responsible for actually starting the software you're really interested in. For `multiprocessing`, `_bootstrap` is responsible for doing the setup required to run your `target` function, and then cleaning up afterwards.